# How to force constructor is only called once without singleton pattern?

Tags: java, design-patterns, singleton

I always read singleton pattern is an anti pattern etc. But I spent nearly a day to find out, that a class had something like a cyclic dependency in construction leading to more than one object, where only one was allowed for the application. That's why I want to verify this never happens again and don't know how to do that without the singleton pattern.

```
public class Application {
    private SingletonModule module;

    public void getModule() {
        if(module == null) {
            module = new SingletonModule(getDependency());
        }
        return module;
    }

    private Dependency getDependency() {
        return new Dependency(getModule());
    }


}

public class Dependency {
    public Dependency(SingletonModule module) {
        System.out.println(module.getAttribute()); // is more complex of course...
    }
}

public class SingletonModule {
    public Dependency dep;
    public String attribute;

    public SingletonModule(Dependency dep) {
        this.dep=dep;
    }

    public String getAttribute() {
        return attribute;
    }

}
```

No the problem is `getModule()` is called from outside, i.e.

```
public class Runner {
     public Runner() {
         Application app = new Application();
         app.getModule().getAttribute();
     }
}
```

Comment: What will happen when calling constructor if it was already called once?

Comment: @namesnik, @Averroes added example code, if I realize this correctly, the singleton pattern won't help much here in SingletonModule, `getModule()` would still be called twice with module beeing `null`, right?

Comment: Module switching is a prime case where I think singletons work great if (1) you have one module on screen at a time, and (2) want to swap screens between multiple modules, making sure each one is destroyed before the next one is loaded. You use a singleton and load a static reference to each module into it the first time that module is requested. If a call comes in for loading another module while the singleton is switching, you either handle that or ignore it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor can check:

```
public class OnlyOne {
    static count = 0;
    public OnlyOne() {
        if (count > 0) throw ...
        count++;
        ...
    }
}
```

or a factory method:

```
public class OnlyOne {
    static count = 0;
    public static OnlyOne make() {
        if (count > 0) throw ...
        count++;
        return new OnlyOne();
    }
    private OnlyOne() { ...}
}
```

Update:
Ideally, creation of this class would be so simple, e.g., when program starts and then passed as dependency, that this check would unnecessary. But if creation happens in a more complex situation, as I assume yours is, then it's a useful safety check.

Comment: I really thought of this, although this feels strange.

Comment: If creation is simple, e.g., when program starts and then passed as dependency, it's probably unnecessary. But if creation happens in more complex situation, I assume yours is, then it's a good safety check.

Comment: You could also use a factory method and do the check there - might be better.

Comment: The difference between this and a singleton being only that it's not putting its own instance into the static var for later retrieval? I agree that using singletons as globals is bad coding practice, but... if you aren't planning on abusing it, what's the point of *not* just making a static reference to the one-and-only instance?

Comment: A code like this is very very very against nature ;) Just imagine how many exceptions would be thrown until developers figure out the nature of the implementation...

Comment: Agree, ideally the creation of this instance should be so simple that this type of check is not necessary.  However, it seems this is not the case in the OP's situation, so this is suggested as a safety check to help in his situation.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with singletons if that's what your application calls for. Static variables exist for a reason. If someone is demanding you do this in an OO way you can make them look ridiculous by creating an object called NotASingletonChecker that performs sixteen checks on a 1-variable-long array, pushing and popping instances of your "NotASingleton" class to it. Make sure you do extensive garbage collection with a "NotSingletonGarbageCollector" class.

Comment: I know drawbacks with threading and clustering, although I'm not sure this is a problem in my special situation...

Comment: In your case a singleton may be the wrong choice - I don't know - but a singleton (e.g. one running on its own process) can just as easily be a way to prevent manage thread race situations as it can be misused to create them. I'd love someone to explain to me what NodeJS is if not a singleton. Anyway, don't discount it just because the religiously anti-singleton lobby says it's an "anti-pattern". Academics and students can argue for purer OO or even functional programming. Working programmers get stuff done. And yeah I'm sure I'll get dv'd for this, but really, what's helpful is what works!

Answer (score 0):

Singleton is not an "anti-pattern". I find this word too...strong.

It is a design pattern as others.
The point is just that it could lead to a very bad practice when overused, for those [reasons](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/scottdensmore/archive/2004/05/25/140827.aspx).
That's why a lot of good developers avoid it when they aren't forced to use it.

**The antipattern would be especially to prevent a natural class (whose constructor is reachable) to spawn more than one object.**

Just make use of the singleton when it makes sense, and in this case...it would.

My preferred solution would be (I imagine you may use Spring..or Guice etc...) to instantiate a bean as singleton. That way, you will end up with a perfect singleton without all these constraints of testing etc.. since your class would appear as a perfect non-singleton-designed class.

Comment: If you look at the code do you really think this is a solution here? I don't see it after this far to long day...

Comment: @jan Updated with my preferred solution.

Comment: And how would this look like in this concrete situation, how does this prevent the dependencies needed for construction? I think there is needed a redesign of the dependencies first, right? After that this might make sense.

Comment: @jan Manage your dependencies with a known and popular container (Spring etc..), don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @jan You may want to read this: http://jeffastorey.blogspot.fr/2009/08/spring-managed-singletons-for.html